# SUDO not found when calling inside a function in BASH script

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, chown, command-not-found

I am trying to create a function in Bash that creates a directory, then sets the ownership, like this:

```
create_dir() {
  local PATH=$1
  local OWNER=$2
  # create log directory
  echo -e "\n* Creating directory $PATH"
  if [[ -d $PATH ]]  
  then
    echo "  * $PATH already exist, no action done"
  else 
    echo "  * $PATH does not exist, creating dir"
    sudo mkdir $PATH
  fi

  sudo chown $OWNER $PATH
}
```

then I call it in the same script like this:

```
# create upload directory, and set owner
create_dir "/www/upload" "deployer"
```

when I execute the script:

```
sudo ./dir_setup.sh
```

it results the following:

*** Creating log directory /www/upload
  * /www/upload already exist, no action done
./dir_setup.sh: line 15: sudo: command not found**

Sudo command is installed and works as expected. The same happens with or without using sudo when calling dir_setup.sh
If I change the line to

```
sudo chown $OWNER $PATH
```

to

```
/usr/bin/sudo chown $OWNER $PATH
```

it works fine. I am logged in as user "deployer" I created, has sudoer rights, the owner of dir_setup.sh the same user, has 777 rights.

If I take that line from the function and put it somewhere else, it also works fine.
Any idea why do I need to call sudo with **/usr/bin/sudo** instead of just calling it using `sudo` when inside a function? And why does it work outside the function?

Comment: Shell variables should be lower-case. Environment variable should be upper-case. (so as to reduce the likely hood of this error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've redefined the reserved variable `$PATH`, which contains the set of locations in which to search for commands such as `sudo`.

Don't use all capitals for your variable names, and all will be well.

```
create_dir() {
  local path="$1"
  local owner="$2"
  # create log directory
  printf "\n* Creating directory %s\n" "$path"
  if [[ -d "$path" ]]  
  then
    printf "  * %s already exists, no action done\n" "$path"
  else 
    printf "  * %s does not exists, creating dir\n" "$path"
    sudo mkdir "$path"
  fi

  sudo chown "$owner" "$path"
}
```

Notice also that I've double-quoted the variables when they are used, so that their values don't get parsed by the shell.

You could also simplify this at the expense of some logging:

```
create_dir() {
    local path="$1" owner="$2"

    printf "\n* Creating directory %s\n" "$path"
    sudo mkdir -p "$path"
    sudo chown "$owner" "$path"
}
```

Comment: OH, thanks, you're completely right!!! I feel so stupid :) But to be honest, i am not a bash expert, as you can see. Thanks for the hints, they are really useful!

Comment: @zak Also relevant: [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847)

Comment: I have renamed all variables to lowercase for safety